# Adding Minimize box to MFC Property Sheet system menu

Tags: visual-c++, mfc

How could I Add **Minimize** and **Maximize** box to the system menu of `CMFCPropertySheet`.
I have tried modifying the style by

```
CMFCPropertySheet::ModifyStyle(NULL, WS_SYSMENU);
```

but nothing happened.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Assuming you have a class derived from CPropertySheet, let's call it MySheet:

```
// Capture the WM_NCREATE message
BEGIN_MESSAGE_MAP(CMySheet, CPropertySheet)
  ON_WM_NCCREATE()
END_MESSAGE_MAP()

BOOL CMySheet::OnNcCreate(LPCREATESTRUCT lpCreateStruct)
{
  if (!CPropertySheet::OnNcCreate(lpCreateStruct))
    return FALSE;

  // Modify the window style
  LONG dwStyle = ::GetWindowLong(m_hWnd, GWL_STYLE);
  ::SetWindowLong(m_hWnd, GWL_STYLE, dwStyle | WS_WS_MINIMIZEBOX | WS_MAXIMIZEBOX);

  return TRUE;
}
```

Note that you could do this in the OnInitDialog, but even though the Minimize/Maximize boxes will show, they won't do anything.

Answer (score 1):

doing just this in the "OnInitDialog:" worked for me.

```
LONG dwStyle = ::GetWindowLong(m_hWnd, GWL_STYLE);
  ::SetWindowLong(m_hWnd, GWL_STYLE, dwStyle | WS_WS_MINIMIZEBOX | WS_MAXIMIZEBOX);
```

Comment: `WS_WS_MINIMIZEBOX` should be `WS_MINIMIZEBOX`, but as Eddie Paz says, the added boxes do nothing.